# combine multiple rows into one in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table through which I am getting some data now given below

```
col1       col2 col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
------------------------------------------------------------
SA106141    ABC test    1400    0       0          58800
SA106141    ABC test    1100    53963   54    54017
SA106141    ABC test    3000    141184  141  141325
SA106141    ABC test    2800    154548  155  154703
SA106141    ABC test    1500    79042   79   79121
SA106141    ABC test    -9800   -487967 0    0
```

but the desired output should be

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
SA106141    ABC test    0      -59229   429       0
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    col1, col2, col3,
    ISNULL(SUM(QTY), 0) AS col4,
    ISNULL(SUM(NET_AMT), 0) AS col5,
    ISNULL(SUM(STT), 0) AS col6,
    CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(SUM(grand_total), 0) <= 0 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE ISNULL(SUM(grand_total), 0)  
    END AS col7
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Dates, TR_DT, TR_NO, SA, GRP, ID, SAID, Exch, Code,
         Client, SCRIPT, BUYSELL, QTY, NT_RT, NET_AMT, 
         QTY * NT_RT AS New_Net_amt,STT,
         ISNULL(NET_AMT + STT,QTY * NT_RT) AS grand_total,
         CAST(SA + GRP + ID + SAID AS VARCHAR(50)) AS testid 
     FROM  
         testtable 
     GROUP BY 
         CAST (SA + GRP + ID + SAID AS VARCHAR(50)), Dates, TR_DT,
         TR_NO, Exch, Code, Client, SCRIPT, BUYSELL, QTY,
         NT_RT, NET_AMT, STT, SA, GRP, ID, SAID) t 
GROUP BY 
    t.testid, t.Dates, t.Client, t.SCRIPT 
ORDER BY 
    t.Client, t.testid, t.SCRIPT, t.Dates ASC
```

Please help

Comment: Can you explain the logic needed to combine the rows? Also, what exactly is the problem with the query you currently have?

Comment: the logic is col2 have multiple record of ABC i just need single ABC  and in that sum of col4 in col4 and col5 and col 6 and abc can be with multiple user like test 1 test 2,test3 soi need a query which shows test1 abc col4 total col5 total col6 total

Comment: the query your pasted doesnt seems to have any relation with the logic you explained here. there are many more columns used in that query!!!

Comment: its a same query i just need a single record of col2

Comment: don't group  by col3 , just use max(col3)

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. In particular give example input, output, desired output, DDL, DML. Use language to say what the output should be in terms of the input. Edit your question to be up to date, don't clarify in comments. If you have a partial solution also give that info for it. PS Your comment is not clear. Use more sentences. You are too terse.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select 
    col1, col2, col3, 
    sum(isnull(col4, 0)) col4, 
    sum(isnull(col5, 0)) col5, 
    sum(isnull(col6, 0)) col6, 
    sum(isnull(col7, 0)) col7
FROM  
     testtable 
group by 
    col1, col2, col3
```